# Javascript custom class, are there side effects?

Tags: javascript

I use the following way to declare a class and create a class object, whether there are side effects?

```
// declare class Hero
var Hero = {
  constructor: function(param) {
    return {
      id: param.id,
      name: param.name
    };
  }
};

// create a class object hero
var hero = Hero.constructor({
  id: 1,
  name: "Windstorm"
});
```

Comment: There are no side effects there. You have a function that always returns the same result given the same inputs.

Comment: I would use const hero..

Comment: @Thalaivar: True, but the code above would appear to be ES5, not ES2015+. In ES2015+, `constructor: function()` could just be `constructor()`, for instance.

Comment: You could rename `Hero.constructor` to something like `create` to avoid confusion.

Comment: It is useful! thank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *code* shown there has no particular side-effects.

A couple of notes though:

- That's not a "class" as the term is usually used in JavaScript. In JavaScript, the term relates to a constructor function and associated prototype. This used to just be convention/common usage, but ES2015 ("ES6") added `class` to the language, giving the term a specific meaning in JavaScript.
- Your `Hero.constructor` function is not a "constructor" function as the term is used in JavaScript, it's a factory function. *Constructor* functions in JavaScript are called via the `new` operator.
- Note that in ES2015 and above, the symbol `constructor` is used to define the constructor function in a `class`.

That doesn't *in any way* make your code incorrect. JavaScript is a hugely flexible language, and there's nothing wrong with using it as you have in your example. Just points out terminology, to avoid confusion later.

Just for clarity, here's an equivalent `Hero` "class" in ES5 and earlier, with a `sayHello` method added to demonstrate the prototype:

```
function Hero(param) {
    this.id = param.id;
    this.name = param.name;
}
Hero.prototype.sayHello = function() { // Or one might well use Object.defineProperty
    console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
};

// Usage
var hero = new Hero({
  id: 1,
  name: "Windstorm"
});
```

And here it is as a class in ES2015+:

```
class Hero {
    constructor(param) {
        this.id = param.id;
        this.name = param.name;
    }
    sayHello() {
        console.log("Hi, my name is " + this.name);
        // or with ES2015's templates:
        //console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}`);
    }
}

// Usage
var hero = new Hero({
  id: 1,
  name: "Windstorm"
});
```

Comment: I always look forward to these kinds of answers.